# How to disable the redirection to Windows lock screen during a remote desktop session?

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-desktop, lock-screen, remmina

I was searching a Linux alternative to TeamViewer, for a remote desktop session on Windows 10, and so I discovered **Remmina**.

I understood how to configure everything making it work, except for the redirection to Windows 10 lock screen: I would prefer make the remote user able to follow what I'm doing, to be transparent, without redirect him/her to the Windows lock screen during my assistance.

Is there **any possible configuration** to disable the lock screen redirection in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that I need to avoid RDP protocol, to solve the unwanted behavior found by using Remmina (and similar), that redirects the remote user to Windows lock screen, allowing only one user to be logged.

Here a list of alternative tools to be tested, hoping to find among them a good alternative to TeamViewer, my preferred choice until discovering a limitation after an intense use, also if for private purpose:

a) NoMachine or NX that use X11 forwarding through SSH protocol

b) Anydesk

c) UltraVNC